# Recommending venues and organizations in a paper

Tags: publications, etiquette

Some co-authors and I are currently writing a position paper that aims to introduce Community A to a set of problems in Community B, in which collaboration between Communities A and B is likely to be helpful.  This paper is intended for submission to a peer-reviewed special issue that has invited such position papers.

There are already some meeting series that are intended to help foster such collaborations, but they are not very widely known.  In our concluding recommendations, we are thinking of including a list of them (perhaps as a table), as an aid for readers who are motivated by our paper to seek out A/B collaborations.

Is such "advertisement" appropriate for a peer-reviewed publication, particularly given that some of the authors are involved in organization of some of the meetings?

Comment: The question will in the end be up to the journal chief editor(s) to decide. I am assuming the publishing is through a journal although it is not explicitly stated.

Comment: @PeterJansson Yes, it's for a journal, as implied by "special issue". However, while ultimately an editor might step in to dictate a choice, I'm more interested in whether it would be perceived as reasonable or unseemly by a *reader*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the *journal* is concerned, this would be a thing to ask your editorial contact at the journal.

As far as the *readers* are concerned, I'd ask myself: what's most useful to the reader? I'd have thought that pointing to an online resource elsewhere, is more useful than a list within the article itself. In an article, the list is frozen in time, and quickly outdated, with no option of maintenance. As a linked external online resource, then there would be the option of updates and maintenance - and even if you don't expect to have the resource yourself to maintain it, someone else might take over the upkeep.

Now, you *would* need to be careful in how you present that online resource, so that it didn't look like spamming (it will help considerably if the resource is not seen as promoting a particular business or university). Precedent is your friend: have a look through recent articles in your target journal, and discuss with your editorial contact at the journal, to find a presentation that will be acceptable to all.

Answer (score 1):

In acknowledgements you can put pretty much anything, as long as it is not too long.

However, if it is anything lengthy (e.g. more than 3 recommendations) I would strongly encourage to put it in a different form than a research paper. Eg. a column in this journal (if it is a applicable), or (in acknowledgements) a link to a website listing opportunities.